# Issue with node-oracledb inside a Docker container

Tags: node.js, oracle, docker, nestjs, node-oracledb

I have a Nest.js app which is connecting to an Oracle database through TypeORM and i'm trying to containerize my application using Docker. So the issue here is that when the app is not containerized it works fine but when I do, I get the following error.

```
[Nest] 19   - 06/16/2020, 4:00:52 AM   [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (4)... +3003ms
 Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help
Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
You must have 64-bit Oracle client libraries in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or configured with ldconfig.
If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html
    at OracleDb.createPool (/app/node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js:202:8)
    at OracleDb.createPool (/app/node_modules/oracledb/lib/util.js:185:19)
```

I made sure to add the dependencies that are needed for the Oracle thin client in my Dockerfile as follows

```
FROM oraclelinux:7-slim
RUN  yum -y install oracle-release-el7 oracle-nodejs-release-el7 && \
   yum-config-manager --disable ol7_developer_EPEL --enable ol7_oracle_instantclient && \
   yum -y install oracle-instantclient19.5-basiclite && \
   rm -rf /var/cache/yum

FROM node:10
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./
```

I am not sure what else to add here to make this work. I got some of the instructions on what to add for oracle client from here https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#docker

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH shouldn't be required with Instant Client 19 RPMs, since it runs ldconfig during package install

Comment: Does a simple sample app work?  If not, share something we can test.  Maybe open a GitHub issue to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use a multi-stage build.  I discussed this in "Node.js Dockerfile Example 3" in my blog posst [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1).

You could try something like:

```
FROM oraclelinux:7-slim as builder

ARG release=19
ARG update=5

RUN yum -y install oracle-release-el7 &&
     oracle-instantclient${release}.${update}-basiclite

RUN rm -rf /usr/lib/oracle/${release}.${update}/client64/bin
WORKDIR /usr/lib/oracle/${release}.${update}/client64/lib/
RUN rm -rf *jdbc* *occi* *mysql* *jar

# Get a new image
FROM node:12-buster-slim

# Copy the Instant Client libraries, licenses and config file from the previous image
COPY --from=builder /usr/lib/oracle /usr/lib/oracle
COPY --from=builder /usr/share/oracle /usr/share/oracle
COPY --from=builder /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get -y dist-upgrade && apt-get install -y libaio1 && \
    apt-get -y autoremove && apt-get -y clean && \
    ldconfig
```

Overall this is probably not worth the complexity.  Look at the other example in the blog post.  Or use Oracle's Dockerfile: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleLinuxDevelopers/oraclelinux7/nodejs/12-oracledb